# VBA: How to use InputBox to prompt user for .txt file path when importing .txt to Excel?

Tags: excel, import, inputbox, vba

I have been following a thread else where that showed me how to use Query Tables in the VBA editor to import a .txt file from a specific path into a worksheet.

The code is as follows:

```
Sub Sample()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Sample.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
        )
        .Name = "Sample"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

I have tried to modify the code so that instead of having to hardcode the path each time, instead a user is prompted for the path with an InputBox that stores the path as a string in a variable, then that variable is called upon instead of the path.

I keep getting errors regarding the .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False line.

Here is my modified code below.

```
Option Explicit
Sub importEXP()

Dim txtloc As String

txtloc = InputBox("Provide path of .txt file to analyze")

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;textloc", destination:=Range("$A$1"))

        .Name = "Sample"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated,

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the line:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;textloc", destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```

With:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & textloc, destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```

Double quotes in VBA don't expand variables (like you can do in PowerShell and Perl); you have to explicitly concatenate.

Comment: Thank you aucuparia. This worked like a charm. Your explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Change
`Connection:="TEXT;textloc"`
to
`Connection:="TEXT;" & textloc`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;textloc", destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```

to

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & textloc, destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```

`textloc` is a variable so it mustn't be placed inside the quotes.